# Convert string (similar json format) to object or array

Tags: php, curl, double, quotes

I receive string "{success: false, errors: { reason: 'text text text' }}" by CURL, how to convert this string to array or object?

String '{"success": "false"....}' may be converted to object by json_decode, but I have string without qoutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex first (it adds quotes)

```
$json = preg_replace ('/(?<!")(?<!\w)(\w+)(?!")(?!\w)/u', '"$1"', $string);
```

After that, you can simply use json_decode()

```
$array = json_decode ($json);
```

### Update

I found this script somewhere:

```
function json_fix_quotes ($string){
    $string = str_replace("{",'{"',$string);
    $string = str_replace(":'",'":"',$string);
    $string = str_replace("',",'","',$string);
    $string = str_replace("'}",'"}',$string);
    return $string;
}
```

Try that instead of the regex

Comment: almost work! after regex string = {"success": "false", "errors": { "reason": '"�"�"�"�"вини�"�"е", "но"'}}. String includes cyrillic symbols and single qoutes

Comment: Great, i've added the flag to my answer

Comment: I find another problem, when `string = {success: true, message: { header: 'reg', text: "\u0412\u044b \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\"}} ` after regexp `string = {"success": "true", "message": { "header": "reg", "text": "\"u0412"\"u044b"&"nbsp";\"u0443"\"u0441"...}}`

Comment: I really dont know how to fix that, it's already a fairly complex regex. Is there no way you can change the source you're receiving the string from to add the quotes there?

Comment: I can't change sourse, but may be something change in CURL? `...curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);...`

Comment: No, that cant be changed. I did found another script though, I added it to my response

Comment: json_fix_quote returns incorrect string `{"success: false, message: {" header":"reg"," text: "\u0412\u044b \u0443..."}}`